# Canvas responsive text

Tags: javascript, canvas

I'm attempting to make a responsive canvas game(using some code found [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/gamedev/comments/4ql0fz/the_best_way_to_make_responsive_canvas_game/) to keep width height 100%). In order to get the text responsive I'm using VW for the size. The problem is that even though I am calling the draw function on a resize, JavaScript still seems to be taking the VW dimension from the original size.(Although reloading the page does correctly size it).

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <title>Game</title>

    <style>
        html body{
            margin:0;
            padding:0;
            border:0;
        }
        #canvas{
            display:block;
            background-color: rgb(102,0,102);
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
<script>
    var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

    //change canvas size
    function canvasSize(){
        canvas.style.width = window.innerWidth + 'px';
        canvas.style.height = window.innerHeight + 'px';
        canvas.width = window.innerWidth * window.devicePixelRatio;
        canvas.height = window.innerHeight * window.devicePixelRatio;
        ctx.scale(window.devicePixelRatio, window.devicePixelRatio);
    }

    //draw function
    function mainDraw(){
        //changing coordinate x,y to centre of canvas
        ctx.translate(canvas.width/2,canvas.height/2);

        //drawing text;
        ctx.font = "2vw Arial";
        ctx.textAlign="center";
        ctx.fillText("RoundCloud Christmas adventure",0,0);

        // draw circle
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(0,0,canvas.width / 100,0,Math.PI*2);
        ctx.closePath();
        ctx.fill();
    }

    window.onload = function(){
        canvasSize();
        mainDraw();
        window.addEventListener('resize', canvasSize);
        window.addEventListener('resize', mainDraw);
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Canvas doesn't support css **`vw`** unit.

SO, you should use ...

```
ctx.font = 2 * window.innerWidth + "px Arial";
```

instead of ...

```
ctx.font = "2vw Arial";
```

Here is the [**working demo on jsFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/8zn4tpkr/)

Comment: Welcome!­­­­­­­